# repo:master and repo1:master are identical

Tags: git, github

I am getting the above message when I am trying to open a pull request from a fork of a main repository back through into the main repository.  Why am I getting the above?  Yes there are changes in the repo1 repository/fork

Comment: Can you attach screenshots please?

Answer (score 0):

> there are changes in the repo1 repository/fork

Then those changes must *not* be in the `repo1/master` branch, since the SHA1 of that branch is identical to `repo/master`.

It is easier to ask for a new pull request done from the correct branch.